# Moving form submit button to Boostrap 5 modal window makes it post data when modal window is opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am making a form for submitting some data and wanted to show an alert with help of Bootstrap Modal with submit input before the data is posted. But when I click the button that should open the modal it immediately submits the form. How can I fix this.

Here is the html of the page. It contains some JSP and EL syntax, just treat it as normal text. I've tried removing it, but the problem remained.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <jsp:include page="components/head-links.jsp"/>
    <title><fmt:message key="application.new-app-title"/> | Digapply</title>
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
<jsp:include page="components/header.jsp"/>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5 mb=3"><fmt:message key="application.new-app-head"/> ${requestScope.faculty.facultyName}</h1>
    <p class="fs-4"><fmt:message key="application.instruction"/></p>

    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller?command=submit-application" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="faculty-id" value="${requestScope.faculty.facultyId}">
        <c:forEach var="subject" items="${requestScope.subjects}">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>${subject.subjectName}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="sid-${subject.subjectId}" class="form-label"><fmt:message key="application.score"/></label>
                        <input required min="0" type="number" class="form-control" id="sid-${subject.subjectId}" name="sid-${subject.subjectId}" placeholder="Score">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="cid-${subject.subjectId}" class="form-label"><fmt:message key="application.certificate-id"/></label>
                        <input required maxlength="9" minlength="9" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$" type="text" class="form-control" id="cid-${subject.subjectId}" name="cid-${subject.subjectId}" placeholder="A1B2-C3D4" aria-label="Last name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#submit-modal"><fmt:message key="application.submit"/></button>
            <div class="modal" id="submit-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-fullscreen-sm-down">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h1><fmt:message key="application.submit-modal-head"/></h1>
                            <p><fmt:message key="application.submit-modal-body"/></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal"><fmt:message key="application.cancel"/></button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="<fmt:message key="application.submit"/>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<jsp:include page="components/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't have `type="submit"`

Comment: I placed it in modal button.